# What is this Javascript Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I have this code which sends a variable to JS from a PHP file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pids = new Array(<?php echo implode(', ', $pids); ?>);
var permalink = "My name is <?php the_permalink(); ?>";
</script>
```

For reasons beyond my comprehension, when take away "My name is", it's a syntax error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pids = new Array(<?php echo implode(', ', $pids); ?>);
var permalink = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>";
</script>
```

There is no output, the script dies on.

```
 [Syntax Error]     

        = new Array(67, 68, 69, 70, 71,
```

The first code was working, now has spontaneously stopped, despite no changes. Now, neither works.

I discovered the problem is the preceding code:
When the less-than sign is changed to less-than-or-equal to, there is a javascript syntax error. Somehow this must break the array or the implode function

```
 $pids = array();
  $i=0;

  $result = count($wpdb->last_result);
  while($i < $result) {    

     $pids[] = $wpdb->last_result[$i]->pid;
     $i++;
  }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pids = new Array(<?php echo implode(', ', $pids); ?>);
var permalink = "My name is <?php the_permalink(); ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Please always add the exact error line if you encounter one.

Comment: Also add the output that was generated from this code.

Comment: What does `var_dump($pids);` look like?

Comment: Can you print_r `$pids` and add the_permalink() function on the question...

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the rendered code 1) when it's correct 2) when if fails.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
var permalink = "My name is '<?php the_permalink(); ?>'";
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably have ' or " inside one of the php output functions, try to escape them.
this could happened also if one of your pids is a wrong type and implode fails to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var permalink = "My name is " + <?php the_permalink(); ?>;
```